# I see the text, but cannot .text return it SOUP

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Running:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search? search_terms=bestbuy+10956&geo_location_terms=10956').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"}):

    info_primary = article.find("div", {"class": "info-section info- 
    primary"}).text

    print(info_primary)
```

`
Yields some noisy (number) characters when yellowpages has a rating for the store. The ratings are stored in "a" tags if they exist, else there is no "a" tag and it goes straight to "p" tags. I wanted to just grab the text from the "p" tags.

Running:

```
info_primary = article.find("div", {"class": "info-section info-primary"}).p.text
```

Gives:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Running:

```
info_primary = article.find("div", {"class": "info-section info-primary"}).p
```

Runs and I can see the text nested, but cannot return it.

Upon looking further, the phone number for the store, which I want, is outside of the "p" tag. Maybe correctly accessing the "span" tags via different class descriptions would help?

Ideas? Thanks!

I am new to Python as a forewarning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: One, you also have to actually `find` the `<p>` tag as well in order to get its text.

Two, if there's no `p` tag and you try to get its text, an `AttributeError` will be raised: you just have to ignore that and go to the next one that may have a `p` (you could also check first to see if `.find('p')` is not None; same effect)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=bestbuy+10956&geo_location_terms=10956').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"}):

    try:
        info_primary = article.find("div", {"class": "info-section info-primary"}).find('p').text
    except AttributeError:
        continue  # If there's no <p> (raises AttributeError) just continue to next loop iteration

    print(info_primary)
```

The reason you could see the `p` tag but not its text is that the text isn't inside the `p` tag, but inside the `span` tags.

You could do

```
    try:
        info_primary = article.find("div", {"class": "info-section info-primary"}).p.span.text
    except AttributeError:
        continue  # If there's no <p> (raises AttributeError) just continue to next loop iteration
```

But that only yields the first `span`'s text. Instead, to get all the `span`'s text you could also do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=bestbuy+10956&geo_location_terms=10956').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for article in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "result"}):

    try:
        span_data = article.find("div", {"class": "info-section info-primary"}).p.find_all('span')
        info_primary = ''
        for span in span_data:
            info_primary += ' ' + span.text
    except AttributeError:
        continue  # If there's no <p> (raises AttributeError) just continue to next loop iteration

    print(info_primary)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Going to try and digest the information you provided and understand what is going on there.

Lastly, at what point can I append additional information. Unfortunately the phone numbers associated to the stores is outside of the p tags and it is in its own div tag just after the /p

Comment: Going to try and learn some more about tags and navigation. 

<div class="phones phone primary" itemprop="telephone">(845) 358-4070</div>

Going to need to learn how to navigate the itemprop portion. Again, calling for text on the div returns attributeerror

Comment: AWESOME NEWS! I am so excited. I carefully understood what you wrote to me and applied it to another try loop! perfect parsing now! Now on to the next step applying the zip code dictionary and multiple requests for the entire USA

Comment: Great, congrats!

Comment: github.com/damoredoo/yellowpages

for final if you would like to see. I am just starting out and was happy to complete this as practice for future projects